# ¿Cómo generar reporte de totales SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, reporte

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
id | nombre   | aula   | asistencia
1  | luis     | aula 1 | S
2  | pedro    | aula 1 | S
3  | juan     | aula 1 | N
4  | andres   | aula 1 | S 
5  | andrea   | aula 2 | N
6  | melisa   | aula 2 | S
7  | cristian | aula 2 | N
8  | felipe   | aula 2 | N
9  | sergio   | aula 2 | S
```

Y quiero obtener un reporte de tipo negocio en al siguiente forma:

```
aula   | total_asistencia | total_sin_asistencia | total_personas
aula 1 | 3                | 1                    | 4 
aula 2 | 2                | 3                    | 5
```

He intentado agrupando por aula pero solo logro sacar un total de esa forma, la consulta que tengo hasta ahora es

```
select t1.aula, count(t1.aula) total_asistencia
from tabla1 t1
where asistencia = 'S'
group by aula
```

Sin embargo no se como sacar los otros totales, pense hacerlo con subquerys pero quisiera hacerlo de manera mas clara.

**Como podría obtener los datos que necesito en SQL? o debo hacerlo en algun lenguaje de programacion fuera de la base de datos?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo podrías resolver mediante una suma condicional:

```
select t1.aula, 
       count(case when asistencia = 'S' then 1 else null end) total_asistencia,
       count(case when asistencia = 'N' then 1 else null end) total_sin_asistencia,
       count(t1.aula) total_personas
       from tabla1 t1
       group by t1.aula
```

En la función de agregación `count()` incorporamos la condición para sumar asistencias o inasistencias en cada columna.